# Simplest way of checking for string that contains a string in list?

Tags: python, string, list

I find myself repeatedly writing the same chunk of code:

```
def stringInList(str, list):
    retVal = False
    for item in list:
        if str in item:
            retVal = True
    return retVal
```

Is there any way I can write this function quicker/with less code?
I usually use this in an if statement, like this:

```
if stringInList(str, list):
    print 'string was found!'
```

Comment: +1 for not just saying "Is there a simply way to ..." and actually showing what you had. Well done

Comment: You don't need a local variable `retVal` in that function, just `return True` when you find it, else `False`.  Skips some unnecessary loops. (and yes, just use `any`)

Comment: Just curious, why do you keep needing this again and again? I can't think of a use case.

Comment: Note that in python you can avoid using this kind of "flag variables". Put a `break` instead of the assignment and then use the `else` clause of the `for` loop to return `False`. In some cases this pattern can improve code readability and avoid too many indentation levels.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Yes, use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(s in item for item in L):
    print 'string was found!'
```

As the docs mention, this is pretty much equivalent to your function, but `any()` can take generator expressions instead of just a string and a list, and `any()` short-circuits. Once `s in item` is True, the function breaks (you can simply do this with your function if you just change `retVal = True` to `return True`. Remember that functions break when it returns a value).

---

You should avoid naming strings `str` and lists `list`. That will override the built-in types.

Comment: +1 For plain and simple but still very useful answer.

Comment: `any` has the efficiency advantage equivalent to that given in @roippi's comment: it just returns `true` on the first instance of a true element, and `false` if it gets to the end without encountering a true element (check out the equivalent code http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any )

Comment: @Haidro - Perfect! Many thanks. I need to read up on generator expressions, clearly.

Comment: you should also avoid naming variables capitalized names like `L` as this goes against PEP8 :)

Comment: @NeilG Actually, quoting the PEP8, it says `When tempted to use 'l', use 'L' instead.` - [link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions)

Comment: That's unfortunate because it also says that instance variables should be "lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability."